# ggplot2 autocomplete giving additional options

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

The autocomplete in RStudio is giving me unnecessary recommendations other than the functions itself e.g. GeomPoint together with geom_point. This also seems specific to `ggplot2` library.

How do I remove the unnecessary GeomPoint autocomplete while still keeping geom_point?

[image]

Comment: GeomPoint is a valid object you can use from ggplot2. If you type "geompoin" that's much closer to "GeomPoint" than "geom_point" on a character-by-character basis. There doesn't appear to be any way to arbitrarily hide certain valid autocomplete options. The list shows you all possible matching objects. You can turn off auto-complete completely if you want.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was a valid object- I should probably read up on what it is used for.

Comment: It's a prototype class in object oriented programming that can be used in cross-package inheritance, which is how ggplot2 supports extension packages. It mostly contains a bunch of functions needed to wrangle the data such that points can be drawn. For example: it has a layer drawing function. It's job is to split up the data into panels and forward it to ta drawing function for panels. The panel drawing function ensures in coordination with the coordinates that the points are drawn at the appropriate x,y position. There is also a function to fill in missing data from the defaults, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MrFlick was absolutely right in the comments that `GeomPoint` is a valid and useful object. However, if you insist on excluding it from autocomplete, you can exclude it from attaching while loading the library. As far as I can tell, plotting should still work.

[image]